# Difference between has_one and belongs_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-one

I am trying to understand `has_one` relationship in RoR.

Let's say I have two models - `Person` and `Cell`:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cell
end

class Cell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Can I just use `has_one :person` instead of `belongs_to :person` in `Cell` model?

Isn't it the same?

Comment: The code above is incorrect, should be `has_one :cell` and `belongs_to :person` there should **not** be a space between the colon and the following word.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

No, they are not interchangable, and there are some real differences.

`belongs_to` means that the foreign key is in the table for this class. So `belongs_to` can ONLY go in the class that holds the foreign key.

`has_one` means that there is a foreign key in another table that references this class. So `has_one` can ONLY go in a class that is referenced by a column in another table.

So this is wrong:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cell # the cell table has a person_id
end

class Cell < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :person # the person table has a cell_id
end
```

And this is also wrong:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cell # the person table has a cell_id
end

class Cell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person # the cell table has a person_id
end
```

The correct way is (if `Cell` contains `person_id` field):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cell # the person table does not have 'joining' info
end

class Cell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person # the cell table has a person_id
end
```

For a two-way association, you need one of each, and they have to go in the right class. Even for a one-way association, it matters which one you use.

Comment: Nice answer. Seeing your answer I realize I read half the question. I'm sorry, but glad that you jumped in.  + 10

Comment: I've had to look this up a billion times. I wish they had thought through the naming a little better, to make it more clear which one goes where.

Comment: Great, now I know the two wrong answers. Would be better to show the "correct" way to show it. Just sayin'.

Comment: I always think of it in terms of Toy Story. Andy 'has_one' Woody, Woody 'belongs_to' andy. Where is the foreign key? On Woody's sole.

Comment: Thinking in terms of Toy Story really helps, so Woody has an 'andy_id' printed on his sole :)

Comment: That's a cool mnemonic, but thought I'd share my mathematical method of remembering.  has_one is like has_many, and has_many implies the key is on the other table since there is fixed number of columns defined on a SQL table.

Comment: @Mike that's so adorable. You're a delight.

Answer (score 15):

If you add "belongs_to" then you got a bidirectional association. That means you can get a person from the cell and a cell from the person.

There's no real difference, both approaches (with and without "belongs_to") use the same database schema (a person_id field in the cells database table).

To summarize: Do not add "belongs_to" unless you need bidirectional associations between models.

Comment: The best line I have read today: "If you add "belongs_to" then you got a bidirectional association. That means you can get a person from the cell and a cell from the person." +1

Answer (score 7):

Using both allows you to get info from both Person and Cell models.

```
@cell.person.whatever_info and @person.cell.whatever_info.
```