# Rails doesn't respect model associations for has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, associations, relationship

**User.rb**

```
has_one :subscription, :inverse_of => :user
```

**Subscription.rb**

```
has_one :credit_card, :inverse_of => :subscription
```

**CreditCard.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :credit_card
belongs_to :subscription, :inverse_of => :credit_card
```

In **credit card controller**:

```
def new
   @credit_card = current_user.build_credit_card
end

def create
   @credit_card = current_user.build_credit_card
end

if @credit_card.save
    if @credit_card.save
    format.html { redirect_to @credit_card, notice: 'Credit card was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @credit_card }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @credit_card.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

However, I'm still able to add multiple credit cards to my user model. How can this be possible? Only a has_many should emit such behaviour if I'm correct? A has_one association should prevent additional entities from being created, apart from one as far as I know..

I tried all variations, but still no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean that it works? What code runs to add multiple cards, and what makes you think it's working when it shouldn't?

Comment: A user has_one credit card, but still any given user is able to create multiple cards? In short, it behaves as if it's a has_many when it's a has_one association. I hope this clarifies my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used a has_one relationship but the power of google and stack overflow has helped me understand this.

[Difference between has_one and belongs_to in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861144/difference-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-rails)

`belongs_to` means that the foreign key is in the table for this class. So belongs_to can ONLY go in the class that holds the foreign key.

```
has_one
```

means that there is a foreign key in another table that references this class. So has_one can ONLY go in a class that is referenced by a column in another table.

Also a nice way to remember it in that post:

> I always think of it in terms of Toy Story. Andy 'has_one' Woody,
>   Woody 'belongs_to' andy. Where is the foreign key? On Woody's sole.

Also this is useful for understanding relationships.

http://requiremind.com/differences-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: For you and me both :)

Comment: Informative BUT...how do you prevent your application from actually creating more than one record (in the op's example, prevent adding multiple credit cards for a user)? Would it be to add to the following to the user model? validates :card_id, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}